# Can an application running as user foo log onto a database as (database) user foobar?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, database

I am writing a simple application that will run as user foo (i.e. Ubuntu user foo).

However, the application will connect to my database as (database user foobar). IIRC, database users have nothing to do with Linux system users - but I just need to clarify that.

So can an app launched to run as user 'foo', connect to a database as user 'foobar' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, the linux login user and the database user are two separate entities.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I thought so, but just had to make sure!